# Making a Sliced Image Responsive?

Tags: css, html

I've experimented with various ways of addressing the problem.

We are using a flash/html5 music player, nested in a graphic design made up of image slices that create a "player" of about `500 x 300px`:

Some text here.

```
    <div id="Major_Glitch_Table">
      <div id="This-Our-Image-01">
        <img src="static/img/This-Our-Image_01.png" width="506" height="122" alt="" />
      </div>

      <div id="This-Our-Image-02">
        <img src="static/img/This-Our-Image_02.png" width="104" height="126" alt="" />
      </div>

      <div id="This-Our-Image-03">
        <!-- start player -->

        <div class="sm2-bar-ui compact">
          <!-- SoundManager2 html5/flash music player here -->
        </div>
        <!-- end player  -->
      </div>

      <div id="This-Our-Image-04">
        <img src="static/img/This-Our-Image_04.png" width="102" height="126" alt="" />
      </div>

      <div id="This-Our-Image-05">
        <img src="static/img/This-Our-Image_05.png" width="300" height="96" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
```

```
Some More Text
```

The CSS:

```
#Major_Glitch_Table {
    position:relative;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    width:506px;
    height:248px;
}

#This-Our-Image-01 {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    width:506px;
    height:122px;
}

#This-Our-Image-02 {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:122px;
    width:104px;
    height:126px;
}

#This-Our-Image-03 {
    position:absolute;
    left:104px;
    top:122px;
    width:300px;
    height:30px;
}

#This-Our-Image-04 {
    position:absolute;
    left:404px;
    top:122px;
    width:102px;
    height:126px;
}

#This-Our-Image-05 {
    position:absolute;
    left:104px;
    top:152px;
    width:300px;
    height:96px;
}
```

I know that a common method is to apply to the image or div:

```
max-width:90%;
height:auto;
```

But then would the percentages of the smaller slices just be set to smaller percentages based on the size ratios?

Now am wondering if there's even any reason no to simply forgo slicing all together and just use the whole graphic as a background image for a div that contains the player.

Then use `background-size: cover;` with a `max-size` on the div as well as the player.

Comment: I think your assumption is correct. It would be easier to use one image. It does depend on how you're loading controls over top of it. Without being able to see it, it makes it difficult to assess.

Comment: Why are you even slicing a 300x500 image?

Comment: You misspelled the site name and after I think I corrected the spelling, I didn't know where the sliced images were.  In any case, it sounds like you should just get rid of the image slicing.

Comment: i removed the comment because of not really wanting to have the url released yet anyway. will post the final approach in case anyone searching is taking the same inadvisable approach.